# Convert CSV to PDF via PHP

Tags: php, pdf, csv, tcpdf

I spent the last day searching for a simple way of converting a csv file to pdf. I found [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and an [example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) of creating a 4-column fixed width table, (and hence can create tables with a low number of columns) but no solution deals with an oversized table spanning multiple landscape pages.

I assume I am not the first one facing this task, so any imput is welcome.

Comment: Read trough the csv file and create an html output for pdf converter like mpdf?

Comment: TCPDF can `AddPage()`